# How to read data (images) faster from AWS S3 buckets?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, amazon-s3, cloud

I wrote the following code to load images from my S3 bucket, do some preliminary preprocessing, and read them into a numpy array:

```
from scipy.misc import imresize
from scipy.misc import imread
import numpy as np
import boto3
import tempfile
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

temp = []
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='ap-northeast-2')  # This is the nearest AWS region to my location

role = get_execution_role()
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')

for img_name in X:
    obj = bucket.Object('ImageFolder/'+img_name)
    obj.download_file(img_name)
    img = mpimg.imread(img_name)
    img = imresize(img, (32, 32))
    img = img.astype('float32')
    temp.append(img)

X = np.stack(temp)
```

But it is taking forever to do this. There are about 20000 images, and it took about 3 hours to finish loading them into `temp`! And at the time of posting this question, it was in the process of putting `temp` into the numpy array `X`, which I suspect might take anything from 1-2 hours. That means this whole process takes around 5 hours to complete, while it only took ***less than a minute*** in my local system (a run-of-the-mill dual core 2.2 GHz CPU, no GPU)! So, how do I make it faster? And is it possible to do this as fast as in my local system?

Comment: You could try a parallelized implementation using multithreading but it's not going to get you down to the "under-minute" run. The reason why is that there is an incurred network overhead from having to fetch the images from S3.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Yeah, I understand the network overhead part; that's why I asked if its even possible to get to "under a minute". Anyway, I just thought of giving AWS a shot, but if I have to incur so much overhead to even get things rolling (transfer files in folders to S3 with aws-cli instead of there being an "upload folder" option in S3 browser, then do multi-threading to read them back...ugh), which was all done in under 3-4 lines of code in my local system, then I am highly disappointed with AWS. The process of transitioning from physical system to cloud should have been much smoother.

Comment: @Kristada673 this is unlikely to have anything to do with AWS performance.  Where are you actually running this? Inside EC2, or externally?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot In a Jupyter notebook inside AWS Sagemaker

Comment: I believe ap-northeast-2 (your bucket region) is not a Sagemaker region. Where are you running this?

Comment: Hong Kong. Yes, it seems you're correct that `ap-northeast-2` is not a Sagemaker region, which I just checked now in their website. I changed the region to `ap-northeast-1` in the code, which is a Sagemaker region, and ran it again. However, I don't notice much (any?) difference in the speed at which it is reading.

Comment: have you looked into if the performance starts off fast and goes down after some images? there are limits on different instance and ebs volume types. some more affordable layouts go full speed until the limit is reached and deteriorate rapidly. this is for amazon a means to give away their infrastructure for free.

Comment: @KavehVahedipour I printed the `img_name` inside the for loop, and there didn't seem to be any difference, eyeballing the console with my eyes, in the rate at which the image names were displayed in the console.

Comment: this is of course when you started your tests not after you had already ran some and were limited by then? i am co-author of a nosql database. some of our customers reported ultra slow import of data. that's how we noticed these limitations exit. once you hit your iops limit, you're out the alone. there is no reason, why aws instances should be inherently slow. at least we don't see that, once our customers by high io instances, which are significantly more expensive.

Comment: @KavehVahedipour I see. Yes, that was when I ran the code the first time. I can write a line to record the time taken every, say, 1000 reads and report if there's any time difference. But if that's the case, then I think this should be mentioned clearly in AWS's S3 documentation, that the puts and gets get throttled after a certain limit. In fact, I found AWS's documentation to be very disorganized. The stuff may be there, but its not easily searchable or finadable. For example, I found out about aws-cli in a stackoverflow post, not when searching "how to upload data to S3" in their website.

Comment: agreed: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-io-characteristics.html was the best i could find. and it remains a little in the dark as to how that effects operation. anyway good luck in you endeavors

Comment: @KavehVahedipour Thank you. I shall update here about whether the reading rate declines over time, or post an answer if I find one to the original question.

Comment: @Kristada673 -- I think if you were to use some of the comments so so far to clarify and expand on your question, it would likely get answered.  You should definitely include details such as the size of the instance running (or other environment like SageMaker), how you're launching the code, and so on.  AWS is a huge, huge world -- be specific about which services you're using and why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html` VPC Endpoints for S3.

Then traffic between your VPC and the other service does not leave the Amazon network, like access S3 bucket via internal network.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html